JRoute not working in my plugin from the backend
I have a weird and strange bug. When I try to use JRoute to prettify my url from Virtuemart it doesn't do anything. Does anyone know how I can fix it?
I read somewhere about using the frontend of the website, but how can I do that?

What code are you currently using to generate URLs?

I solved it by creating a frontend plugin where I use ajax to generate the JRoute via the frontend, i will post the answer soon
